# Android SearchView setOnActionExpandListener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview

I need to intercept when my SearchView is collapsing or not, in order to change some fragments in my Activity, that is an AppCompatActivity.
I created a listener with the method *MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener* but it seems that it's never called.
Also strange thing, in my method *onOptionsItemSelected*, after some debug, I checked that still here I can't itercept nothing. I tried various method founded here about this problem, but no way to resolve it.
Here is my code:

**menu_search_cat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".CategoriesActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"  />
```

**CategoriesActivity**

```
import android.widget.SearchView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);

    ...

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search_cat, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new     MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSearchViewExpand");
            }
            toggleDown();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);

            SuggestionsFragment newFragment = SuggestionsFragment.newInstance(mBusiness);

            ft.replace(R.id.category_container, newFragment, "suggestionsFragment");
            ft.addToBackStack(null);

            ft.commit();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSearchViewCollapse");
            }
            FragmentTransaction ft =          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);

            MacroCategoriesFragment newFragment = new MacroCategoriesFragment();

            ft.replace(R.id.category_container, newFragment, "macrocatFragment");

            ft.commit();
            return true;
        }
    });


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: "+item.toString());
    }
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search) {
        //never work here
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem: the onActionExpandListener works only if the ActionView of my MenuItem is marked also as *collapseActionView* in my menu file. So I modified it in this way:

```
<item 
  android:id="@+id/search"
  android:title="@string/search_title"
  android:orderInCategory="1"
  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
  app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"  />
```

Comment: But it makes it expanded all the time, useless!